# How Can I Display this better?

Tags: php, mysql

My code seems to be working okay .. but it just seems like a lot of copy and paste code to suit to each food. I only have copied and pasted the code for two of variables, but thinking there must be an easier way?

I am currently displaying meals in relation to 'keywords' which they were able to select which ones they prefer via a form. 
Basically, what it's doing is displaying meals based on their preferences(which they completed via a checkbox form)
Also, i NEED the variables to define the word, for example, $1='Option1' and also the =1 means they user checked the checkbox.

If anyone can help me out here that would be really much appreciated.

Comment: put each food value in array and loop through array and do what you want

Comment: Can you help give me an example? Do you mean -  $meals = array("", "", ""); as i have tried this, however i need both the B1='eggs' how can i put all of those in an array?

Comment: Where do `$B1` and `$B2` come from? show the code! Also this code is wrong: `if($B1 = '1')`. It should be `if($B1 == '1')` same for `$B2`

Comment: It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to achieve here

Comment: In the table RESULTS (gained from user preferences) it will have B1 straight to B6- showing either 1 or 0 for that user whether they have selected it or not.

Comment: Well show the code for RESULTS - it needs improvement as well.

Comment: I'm going to guess that what you really want to do is `JOIN` the two tables.

Comment: Please update question with additional code and try writing clean code it not good habit to learn writing bad... You have many mistakes

Comment: Yes, but i need to write that code for EACH one, that's the part i need to cut down? There surely must be an easier way?

Comment: So you have `$B1=$_POST['1']` somewhere?

Comment: If you want to get `FoodQuestionnaireResults` user that have some id and you want that id to be in `Recipes` where keyword = something.

I think short way would be:


`SELECT * FROM FoodQuestionnaireResults WHERE userid='$userid' AND userid IN (SELECT id FROM Recipes WHERE keyword = $keyword)`


And then do what you want

Comment: You're aware that your `FoodQuestionnaireResults` query isn't actually being executed at all, right? You're assigning it to `$dbQuery` and then immediately overwriting it with your other query.  So if "My code seems to be working okay" is really true, then I'm not sure you understand what you're actually doing.

Comment: Patrick: The code isn't working. But he is seeking information about how to put it in a loop.

Comment: @Adder The whole question is moot if the OP doesn't understand what's going on because if you don't understand, then you can't explain to others (us).

Comment: @user1251007 It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela: Thank you for the kind explanation! I will consider that in the future.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to access your variables and fetch the recipes for each. It would be better to put them in an array, but I didn't make that change since I don't know where you get the $B1 from.

```
include ("dbConnect.php");
  $A1 = ("cheese");
  $A2 = ("yoghurt");
  $A3 = ("egg");
  $A4 = ("fruit");
  $A5 = ("cereal");
  $A6 = ("oatmeal");

$dbQuery=$conn->prepare("select * from FoodQuestionnaireResults where UserID=$UserID");
$dbQuery->execute();

while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    for($i = 1; $i<=6; ++$i) {
        $bname = "B$i";
        $$bname = $dbRow[$bname];
    }
}

for($i = 1; $i<=6; ++$i) {
    $aname = "A$i";
    $bname = "B$i";
    if ($$bname == '1') 
    {
        $dbQuery=$conn->prepare("select * from Recipes where Keyword = '".($$aname)."'");
        $dbQuery->execute();

        while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
                echo "<br><br><h4>".$dbRow["Name"]."</h4><br>"."<br><img src=Breakfast/".$dbRow['Picture']."' width='150' height='150' />"."<br><br>".$dbRow['Instructions'];
         }
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
 }
```

I'm using weird but working code like `$$aname` to access `$A1` to `$A6` and `$$bname` to access `$B1` to `$B6`

Change the HTML to:

```
<h1>Question 1</h1><br>
 </br>
  <h4> What types of food do you like to eat for Breakfast?</h4><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="B1" value="Cheese">Cheese
  <input type="checkbox" name="B2" value="Yoghurt" >Yoghurt
  <input type="checkbox" name="B3" value="Eggs">Eggs
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="button-form"></center></br>
```

Comment: It is returning me  nothing back here. I also have the user results set all to 1 to see.

Comment: $B1..$B6 are the user results?

Comment: the code above brings back : Notice: Undefined variable: B1 in /homepages/28/d706589850/htdocs/breakfast.php on line 136


The A1-A6 need defined as B1-B6, but still doesnt bring me back anything?

Comment: Yes I asked for $B1..$B6 what your code was for them, but you didn't add information about that to your question.

Comment: see edited above.

Comment: I edited it, it should be complete now.

Comment: $name is undefined?

Comment: My workday is nearing its end. So I can't debug this with you. Use `echo $B1;` and `print_r($dbrow);` to see which parts of your code work and which ones need improvement.

Comment: $name isn't defined anywhere though? If you could just tell me what $name is meant to be?

Comment: It should be `$bname`

Comment: This works perfectly now! THANKS so much for your help @Adder